# Need real time collaboration feature for sheet widget in Jupyter Labs

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I need to know if there is a way to use ipysheet or any similar widget in Jupyter lab with its real time collaboration feature such that multiple users can edit and save the data displayed in the sheets.

So, far I have not been able to find a way to do this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.